# Start outer scroll when inner scroll reaches lower or upper edge

Tags: javascript, polymer, dom-events, web-component, lit-element

Imagine I have two scrollable divs, one inside another. when I scroll inner div, when I finish scroll all  the way down or all the way up, I want now outer scrollbar to start scrolling, but in my case it doesn't start. How can I achieve this? In my opinion the problem is that inner scroll happens inside shadow dom, and this stops propagation of scroll event on the outer div.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep scrolling. it seams to work this way already

```css
 .FixedHeightContainer
{
  float:right;
  height: 130%;
  width:250px; 
  padding:3px; 
  background:#f00;
}
.Content
{
   height:224px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<html style="height:100%;">
<head>
 
</head>
  <body style="height:100%;">
      <div class="FixedHeightContainer">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="Content">
     blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it works in for this case, but as I said I have inner div inside shadow dom, and it doesn't propagate scroll on outer div by itself